# VS Code custom syntax highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to ask for help. I have file with custom format. Each line looks similair to this:

```
T   S   123456  0   0.3 -0.9    -0.2    V   paramName
```

Records are separated by tabs (\t)
Basically, i only want to highlight, lets say each word (column, because there will be a lot of those lines) by diferent style/color - it does not matter. I read a lot about custom grammars for VS Code, but I still does not have any idea, how to do it.

One of my attempts:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "Testlist for DataExpress",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#records"
        },
        {
            "include": "#keywords"
        }

    ],
    "repository": {
        "keywords": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "keyword.control.tsv",
                "match": "\\b(TSTLST|Program|Device|Comment)\\b"
            }]
        },
        "records":{
            "match": "T\tS\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+.[0-9]+\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+\t.*\t.*",
            "captures": {
                "1": {
                    "name":"keyword.operator.new"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name":"markup.bold"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name":"variable"
                },
                "4": {
                    "name":"entity.name.class"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.tsv"
}
```

Idea behind was, get back list defined by regexp and then each capture format in different way.
I know, thats a silly idea, but as I said, i am out of ideas  for now.

Thanks a lot

**Edit**

From comment:

Correct regexp is :

```
(T\tS\t)([0-9]+\t[0-9]+)(\t[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+)(\t.*)(\t.*)
```

Comment: you don't define capture groups `()` in your `records` `match` string

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you man :) you got the point, thanks a lot. I upvote your comment, then by accidentally downvote arrrrgh. I can't again it upvote. Yes that is a solution. Thank you for enlightment ;) have a nice day. Correct regexp is :
(T\tS\t)([0-9]+\t[0-9]+)(\t[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+\t[+-][0-9]+.[0-9]+)(\t.*)(\t.*)

Comment: why do you color the tab characters

Comment: @rioV8 the file has a fixed structure and it is neccessary to use as delimitter \t And this way, you are able to see immediatly that some tabs are missing, and there are spaces for example. of course it is verified by scripts, but when you modify it this can be pretty handfull, i think

Comment: but if it uses spaces the regex will not match so the whole line is uncolored

Comment: @rioV8 I got your point, but i think this is desired state, because if there will be not tabs, file will be not processed, so that is basically okay. Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241548/discussion-between-kalikadze-and-riov8).